# No statements being executed after Task finishes in async task, but nearly identical async task works just fine

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using an async task as the method that fires when a button is clicked. It opens a custom popup, which then returns a device object. That device object is then supposed to be added to the list. However, it isn't added to the list because that statement is never executed. However, I have a very similar method that opens a very similar custom popup and returns a list, and that method works just fine; all of the statements after the popup closes execute as expected. The code for the method **that does not work** is here:

```cs
        async Task Modify(Device dev)
        {
            //code to create the popup which allows you to update things
            Device result = await ModifyPopup.DevInfoInvoke(dev,Navigation);
            devices[devices.IndexOf(dev)] = result;//statement that never executes
        }
```

And the code for the method **that does work** is here:

```cs
async Task InfoAdd(ReturnedImg img,bool isvis,string type="")
        {
            //code to create the popup, which returns the type and value
            List<string> result = await DevInfoPopup.DevInfoInvoke(img, Navigation, isvis);
            //if the type string isn't blank then change the result[0] (type) value to type
            if (type != "")
            {
                [code not relevant to the question]
            }
        }
```

The "DevInfoInvoke" method in the popup associated **with the method that does not work** is as follows:

```cs
public static async Task<Device> DevInfoInvoke(Device dev, INavigation navigation)
        {
            //creates a taskcompletion source to hold the result of the button click; the task is set to complete when the list is passed to it
            //then, this list is returned
            TaskCompletionSource<Device> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Device>();
            void callback(Device result)
            {
                completionSource.TrySetResult(result);
            }
            var popup = new ModifyPopup(dev, callback);
            await navigation.PushPopupAsync(popup);
            return await completionSource.Task;
        }
```

And the "DevInfoInvoke" method in the popup associated **with the method that does work** is as follows:

```cs
public static async Task<List<string>> DevInfoInvoke(ReturnedImg img, INavigation navigation, bool dropvis)
        {
            //creates a taskcompletion source to hold the result of the button click; the task is set to complete when the list is passed to it
            //then, this list is returned
            TaskCompletionSource<List<string>> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<List<string>>();
            void callback(List<string> result)
            {
                completionSource.TrySetResult(result);
            }
            var popup = new DevInfoPopup(img,callback,dropvis);
            await navigation.PushPopupAsync(popup);
            return await completionSource.Task;
        }
```

Is there anything I'm missing here? I don't understand why the second statement of the Modify method never executes under any circumstances, but the if statement and beyond in the InfoAdd statement always execute under all circumstances. Thanks for the help :)

**UPDATE Here is the Minimal Reproducible example:**
Here is the xaml code for the main page:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AsyncErrorMRP.MainPage">
    <StackLayout x:Name="main"/>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the c# code for the main page:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AsyncErrorMRP
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public Button test_button;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            test_button = new Button() { Text = "Click Me" };
            test_button.Clicked += async (sender, args) => await click_event();
            main.Children.Add(test_button);
        }
        async Task click_event()
        {
            //creates the popup and awaits the result
            bool result = await TestPopup.DevInfoInvoke(Navigation);
            //if the code worked correctly, this if statement would execute and the text on the button would change
            if (result)
            {
                test_button.Text = "True";
            }
            else
            {
                test_button.Text = "False";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml code for the custom popup:

```xml
<popups:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AsyncErrorMRP.TestPopup"
             CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked="False"
             xmlns:popups="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup">
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Button Text="True" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" BorderWidth="3" BorderColor="Black" Clicked="True"/>
        <Button Text="False" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" BorderWidth="3" BorderColor="Black" Clicked="False"/>
    </StackLayout>
</popups:PopupPage>
```

And here is the c# code for the custom popup:

```cs
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Extensions;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace AsyncErrorMRP
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TestPopup : PopupPage
    {
        private readonly Action<bool> setResultAction;
        public TestPopup(Action<bool> setResultAction)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public void True(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setResultAction?.Invoke(true);
            this.Navigation.PopPopupAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        public void False(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setResultAction?.Invoke(false);
            this.Navigation.PopPopupAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        public static async Task<bool> DevInfoInvoke(INavigation navigation)
        {
            //creates a taskcompletion source to hold the result of the button click; the task is set to complete when the list is passed to it
            //then, this list is returned
            TaskCompletionSource<bool> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            void callback(bool result)
            {
                completionSource.TrySetResult(result);
            }
            var popup = new TestPopup(callback);
            await navigation.PushPopupAsync(popup);
            return await completionSource.Task;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this example helps.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line of the method that doesn't work and step through it.

Comment: What is `devices` and how do you verify that `devices[devices.IndexOf(dev)] = result;` never executes?

Comment: The first thing I tried was using a breakpoint; the breakpoint was never reached. Devices is a class I created that is empty except for having fields for serial number, mac address, and universal product code.

Comment: Ensure you are not [blocking on asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) anywhere further up your call stack. If you're not, then please post a minimal repro.

Comment: Yeah nothing is blocked so I'll try to do that

Comment: @StephenCleary I have posted the reprex

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the error was a missing line of code in the constructor of the popup page. The correct constructor was:

```cs
public TestPopup(Action<bool> setResultAction)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.setResultAction = setResultAction;//missing line of code
        }
```

This sets the readonly Action variable so that clicking on the buttons in the popup actually causes a value to be returned instead of only closing the popup.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Action is used in your example, so only Action can be used to achieve the function you want.
Here is the c# code for the MainPage:

```
public Button test_button;
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    test_button = new Button() { Text = "Click Me" };
    test_button.Clicked += async (sender, args) => await click_event();
    main.Children.Add(test_button);
}
async Task click_event()
{
    var page1 = new TestPopup();
    page1.setResultAction += (r) =>
    {
        if (r)
        {
            test_button.Text = "True";
        }
        else
        {
            test_button.Text = "False";
        }
    };
    await Navigation.PushAsync(page1);
}
```

Here is the c# code for the TestPopup:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class TestPopup : PopupPage 
{
    public  Action<bool> setResultAction;
    public TestPopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void True(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setResultAction(true);
        Navigation.PopAsync();   
    }
    public void False(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setResultAction(false);
        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I tried this I got the exception "'PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage". What version of android are you running?

Comment: Change to MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()); in App.xaml.cs